# Electron.Net default menu shows before click, then custom menu loads

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, electron, electron.net

I'm using Electron.Net to wrap an ASP.Net MVC webpage, and I'm currently trying to replace the default menu. I've got a custom menu working, and the code is replacing the menu. But when the program is run using `electronize start`, the default menu shows until I click on the leftmost default item (`file`). Once I click on the item, my menu loads.

I think the issue is related to the MenuController only running when the Menu is interacted with, so I think I need to implement some kind of async capabilities. I do not know how to do this, I've looked online but not found much.

MenuController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
            {
                MenuItem[] menu = new MenuItem[]
                {
                    new MenuItem
                    {
                        Label = "File",
                        Submenu = new MenuItem[]
                        {
                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Open",
                                Accelerator = "CmdOrCtrl+O"
                            },
                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Save",
                                Accelerator = "CmdOrCtrl+S"
                            },
                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Save As",
                                Accelerator = "CmdorCtrl+Shift+S"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    new MenuItem
                    {
                        Label = "Edit",
                        Submenu = new MenuItem[]
                        {
                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Preferences"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    new MenuItem
                    {
                        Label = "View",
                        Submenu = new MenuItem[]
                        {
                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "TODO"
                            },

                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Reload",
                                Click = () =>
                                {
                                    Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.ToList().ForEach(BrowserWindow =>
                                    {
                                        if (BrowserWindow.Id != 1)
                                            BrowserWindow.Close();

                                        else
                                            BrowserWindow.Reload();
                                    });
                                }
                            },

                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Toggle Full Screen",
                                Accelerator = "CmdOrCtrl+F",
                                Click = async () =>
                                {
                                    bool isFullScreen = await Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().IsFullScreenAsync();
                                    Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().SetFullScreen(!isFullScreen);
                                }
                            },

                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Type = MenuType.separator
                            },

                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Open Developer Tools",
                                Accelerator = "CmdOrCtrl+Shift+I",
                                Click = () =>
                                {
                                    Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().WebContents.OpenDevTools();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    new MenuItem
                    {
                        Label = "Navigate",
                        Submenu = new MenuItem[]
                        {
                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Home",
                                Submenu = new MenuItem[]
                                {
                                    new MenuItem
                                    {
                                        Label = "Home",
                                        Click = () =>
                                        {
                                            Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().LoadURL($"http://localhost:{BridgeSettings.WebPort}/");
                                        }
                                    },

                                    new MenuItem
                                    {
                                        Label = "Privacy",
                                        Click = () =>
                                        {
                                            Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().LoadURL($"http://localhost:{BridgeSettings.WebPort}/Privacy");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Type = MenuType.separator
                            },

                            new MenuItem
                            {
                                Label = "Editor",
                                Submenu = new MenuItem[]
                                {
                                    new MenuItem
                                    {
                                        Label = "Editor",
                                        Click = () =>
                                        {
                                            Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First().LoadURL($"http://localhost:{BridgeSettings.WebPort}/Editor/");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                Electron.Menu.SetApplicationMenu(menu);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Views/Editor/Index.cshtml

```
@model CircuitSharp.Models.EditorModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!--
    EDITOR INDEX PAGE
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Editor</title>

    <!-- 
        IMPORTING THE CUSTOM MENU
    -->
    <link rel="import" href="Menu" />
</head>
<body>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just re-ran the program the next day and it works now. ¯_(ツ)_/¯